# MySQL select only 1 per match

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 5 rows:

```
email
message_id
date
time
```

And I would like to count the number of emails there is per days.

So far I have this

```
SELECT Date,COUNT(*) AS Num FROM mail2_mailing_log WHERE Id_message=@Id GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date DESC
```

But we found out that there was a problem with a script and many data got multiplied (Which have since been fixed), but I would like to be able to use the data I have.

So basically I would want to "merge" all the rows that match per email, date and time and then group by date and count the number of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT q.date, COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT email, date, time
              FROM mail2_mailing_log
              WHERE Id_Message = @Id) q
    GROUP BY q.date
    ORDER BY q.date DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the distinct keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date,COUNT(*) AS Num FROM mail2_mailing_log WHERE Id_message=@Id GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Date column contains the time too, then you will need to format the Date column using the  `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%W %M %Y'),COUNT(*) AS Num FROM mail2_mailing_log
WHERE Id_message=@Id GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%W %M %Y')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%W %M %Y') DESC
```

Comment: Just realised about the GROUP BY and updated.  Removed the distinct too.